# Divergence of $n!^{1/n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to find a simple proof that $n!^{1/n}$ is a divergent sequence. I have proved it using a lower bound you can get from an integral (or Stirling's approximation) that $n!^{1/n}>\ln(n)$, but I get the impression from the other questions I've done that it shouldn't need all that machinery.

Hints would be preferred to full solutions, please

Comment: @Jonas Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 6):

Hint; At least half the terms in the product for $n!$ will be at least $n/2$, so$$n! \geq (n/2)^{n/2}$$ which shows the result.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$(n+1)\log(n+1)-n\log n = n\log(1+1/n)+\log(n+1) \leq 1+\log(n+1)$$
we have:
$$\log(n!) \geq 1-n+n\log n$$
hence:
$$\log\left(n!^{1/n}\right) \geq \log n-1$$
and $a_n=n!^{1/n}$ satisfies $a_n\geq \frac{n}{e}.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: can you write a polynomial expression for $n!$?  What is its lead term?

Comment: You _can't_ write a polynomial expression for $n!$ (unless you use an infinite polynomial).

Comment: I'll admit it is early and I am tired, but for specific $n$ a positive integer I'm fairly sure that $n! = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (n-k)$ is a polynomial in $n$.

Comment: Oh, I had assumed you meant one polynomial that works for all $n$.

Comment: Ah, right.  Yes, that would be bad!

Comment: No, that would be awesome=)